# Top few numbers (highest) of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list

```
A = {51, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 52, 55};
```

How do I get the highest three numbers of `A` to get

```
{51, 52, 55}
```

I can think of ranking them first, but is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Does the order in the result matter?

Comment: Maybe `Sort[A][[-3;;]]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the order does not matter, `TakeLargest[A, 3]`; if it does, `A[[Ordering[A, -3]]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
MaximalBy[A, Identity, 3]
```